# Grabwidget to grab the complete view even if it is zoomed in

Tags: qt, qpixmap

I am using 
`QPixmap QPixmap::grabWidget ( QWidget * widget, int x = 0, int y = 0, int width = -1, int height = -1 )`  to grab the viewport in `QPixmap object`.

In some case even if the screen is zoomed in to some level, i want to grab the complete screen which will be scrolled out that moment. Does some variant of `grabwidget` or any other function facilitate that?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way or another, I think you will need to set the resolution of your object to the size you want for your "screenshot".  Below are a few different ideas of things to try:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html#grabWidget

> This function actually asks widget to paint itself (and its children to paint themselves) by calling `paintEvent()` with painter redirection turned on.

Make a switch for your widget to use a modified viewport.  Then right before calling grabWidget, set the switch to use a full-resolution viewport ([`QPainter::setViewport()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#setViewport)), and then after you finish grabWidget, reset the switch.  You can also look at the source for grabWidget in QPixmap.cpp (link to [src](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.8/src/gui/image/qpixmap.cpp)).

Maybe changing how your widget responds in a scroll area can make a difference.  [`QScrollArea::setWidgetResizeable()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qscrollarea.html#widgetResizable-prop).

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/desktop-screenshot.html

In the desktop screenshot example, they hide the window of the screenshot utility right before taking the screenshot, and then reshow the window afterwards.

So to apply this principle to your application, you could draw the widget at its full resolution temporarily, and then call `grabWidget` and then rezoom and redraw at the previous resolution.

You could also try looking at how QPrinter works, and if there is a way to use it in your application.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprinter.html#details

Hope that helps.