# Change viewport to full resolution

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a QGraphicsView with a different width and length to the pixmap I want to save. When I save the pixmap, I want it to be on full resolution.

```
def save(self):
    painter = QtGui.QPainter()
    painter.setViewport(rect.toRect())
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap().grabWidget(self)
    pixmap_scaled = pixmap.scaled(1275, 2004, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
    pixmap_scaled.save('sample.png')
```

when I do this, the pixmap is not on full resolution.

The code below is the fitinview code for the high resolution image to fit the qgraphicsview

```
    def fitInView(self, scale=True):
        rect = QtCore.QRectF(self._photo.pixmap().rect())
        if not rect.isNull():
            self.setSceneRect(rect)
            if self.hasPhoto():
                unity = self.transform().mapRect(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 1, 1))
                self.scale(1 / unity.width(), 1 / unity.height())
                viewrect = self.viewport().rect()
                scenerect = self.transform().mapRect(rect)
                factor = min(viewrect.width() / scenerect.width(),
                         viewrect.height() / scenerect.height())
                self.scale(factor, factor)
            self._zoom = 0
```

My QGraphicsView

```
class FrontGraphics(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
photoClicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtCore.QPoint)

def __init__(self, parent):
    super(FrontGraphics, self).__init__(parent)
    self._zoom = 0
    self._empty = True
    self.setMouseTracking(True)
    self._scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self)
    self._photo = QtGui.QGraphicsPixmapItem()
    self._scene.addItem(self._photo)
    self.setScene(self._scene)
    self.setTransformationAnchor(QtGui.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
    self.setResizeAnchor(QtGui.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
    self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
    self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
    # self.setBackgroundBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(30, 30, 30)))
    self.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.NoFrame)
    # self.setFixedSize(350, 600)
    self._idpicture = IDPicture(QtCore.QPointF(50, 50))
    self._scene.addItem(self._idpicture)
    self._studentid = StudentId()
    self._scene.addItem(self._studentid)
    self._fullname = FullName()
    self._scene.addItem(self._fullname)
    self._section = Section()
    self._scene.addItem(self._section)
```

My QWidget

```
class FrontWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
def __init__(self):
    super(FrontWindow, self).__init__()
    self.viewer = FrontGraphics(self)
    self.btnLoad = QtGui.QToolButton(self)
    self.btnLoad.setText('Load image')
    self.btnLoad.clicked.connect(self.loadImage)
    self.btnClear = QtGui.QToolButton(self)
    self.btnClear.setText('Clear')
    self.btnClear.clicked.connect(self.clearImage)
    self.btnPixInfo = QtGui.QLabel(self)
    self.setFixedWidth(500)
    self.setFixedHeight(800)
    self.setGeometry(500, 300, 500, 300)
    # Arrange layout
    VBlayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
    VBlayout.addWidget(self.viewer)
    HBlayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    HBlayout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
    # HBlayout.addWidget(self.btnLoad)
    HBlayout.addWidget(self.btnClear)
    HBlayout.addWidget(self.btnPixInfo)
    VBlayout.addLayout(HBlayout)
```

I tried the answer here [Grabwidget to grab the complete view even if it is zoomed in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738165/grabwidget-to-grab-the-complete-view-even-if-it-is-zoomed-in) but can't do it

Comment: What is the meaning of *full resolution*?

Comment: The self._photo resolution is 1275 x 2004 and I can't display it on QGraphicsScene because it does not fit. I used fittoresize so it can fit the QGraphicsView which cannot fit the original resolution(1275 x 2004). I want the pixmap to save with the resolution of 1275 x 2004 without scaling.

Comment: with the fitInView() method you are scaling the item to the size of the viewport(), and it is understood that this transformation is lost, so the only way to obtain an image of the same size is to scale it again, that brings as a consequence that the original image and the generated image are not the same. So it will be impossible to do what you want.

Comment: I'm thinking of calling fitInView() method after saving the image, in that way, the image will save without sacrificing resolution and at the same time, the display will still fit the view.