# How do I print a scrolling GUI designed using QtDesigner in python?

Tags: python, user-interface, printing, qt-designer

I want to print the entire scroll area of the GUI. Currently I am only printing a screenshot of the visible portion of the GUI. Furthermore, none of the printer settings I am setting are being utilized, instead the default printer settings are used. See below for code sample and GUI. Thanks.

```
def printform(self):
    dialog = QtPrintSupport.QPrintDialog()
    if dialog.exec_() == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
        # Create printer
        printer = QtPrintSupport.QPrinter()
        printer.setprintrange = printer.AllPages
        printer.setPageSize = printer.Letter
        printer.setOrientation = printer.Landscape
        # Create painter
        painter = QtGui.QPainter()
        # Start painter
        painter.begin(printer)
        # Grab a widget you want to print, self.grab() for entire screen
        screen = self.grab()           
        # Draw grabbed pixmap
        painter.drawPixmap(10, 10, screen)
        # End painting
        painter.end()
```

[image]

Comment: Just to get that clear, you want to print on an actual paper printer the GUI as it is, with text fields, etc. ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169329/screenshot-of-a-qt-application-from-inside-the-application

Comment: Is this supposed to be the "real" printing solution when someone is using the application later?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738165/grabwidget-to-grab-the-complete-view-even-if-it-is-zoomed-in

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtprintsupport-index.html  and https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtprintsupport-index.html#printing-widgets

Comment: @Joe Yes I want to print the GUI on actual paper as it is, with all fields.